# How to host NestJS Backend in shared hosting Cpanel?

Tags: nestjs, cpanel, shared-hosting

Though there are plenty of solutions for **NodeJS** backends but I can hardly find any solution to host **NestJS** backend in a shared hosting cpanel. As of the time of writing this, there's hardly 3-5 questions related to this in stackoverflow and some of them aren't even answered yet. Those which are answered, the answers aren't sufficient for any beginner.

All I can assume is that, as NestJS is totally written on TypeScript,it needs to be compiled into JS. Nest project has a `dist` folder, which contains the total project complied in JS.

But how can I host it in Cpanel? (any thorough answer will be appreciated)

Comment: Can you please show us where cpanel claims to support node applications? Maybe also follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404516/missing-setup-node-js-application-button-in-cpanel

Comment: @OneCricketeer  You can install NodeJS in Cpanel.

https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

Comment: NestJS is a NodeJS framework, not its own thing, so what specific issues are you having with the existing instructions?

Comment: @OneCricketeer When I upload a basic 'hello world' nestJS backend, it works perfectly. I take the contents of `dist` folder and the `package.json` file, upload it accordingly, and then `npm install`. It runs well.

But the when I do the same for a complex nestJS backend, it gives 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup Node.JS App CPanel Menu -> Setup Node.JS App -> Create Application ...
   Compile Website Files ...
2. Compress/Zip the contents of ‘dist’ for convenient upload to CPanel. ...
3. Upload compressed local ‘dist’ directory (dist.zip) to the CPanel Filesystem
4. nodejs app directory generated in step 2. ...
5. Extract the contents of your uploaded .zip file into the CPanel Filesystem ‘dist’ directory.

Comment: Nice response, is there a way to do CI/CD from github to host on a cpanel site like hostblast.online???